# Having a error code when I am trying to replace genre_ids

Tags: python, lambda, replace

```
KeyError: '['
```

What I've tried:

```py
id_code = {'28': 'action', '12': 'adventure', '16': 'animation'.....}

merged_df['genre_ids'] = merged_df.genre_ids.apply(lambda x: [id_code[i] for i in x])
```

What I expect: in `genre_ids` column to have the names of genre instead of ids number:

```
[28,16] -- action, aventure
```

Comment: Show us some sample values of `merged_df.genre_ids`.

Comment: It looks like `x` is in your case not a list but it's a string.

Comment: As @codester_09 said, it looks like those values aren't lists; they're _strings_ that happen to look like lists.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

It looks like `x` is in your case a string in a list format.

```
from ast import literal_eval


id_code = {'28': 'action', '12': 'adventure', '16': 'animation'.....}

merged_df['genre_ids'] = merged_df.genre_ids.apply(lambda x: [id_code[i] for i in literal_eval(x)])
```